# Zoom preview for curve bend filter

Tags: gimp, zoom

Is there a way to zoom the preview image for the curve bend distortion filter in Gimp 2.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately **no**. The dialog uses a simple preview widget which does not allow zooming.

For what it's worth: some plug-ins have been updated to use a newer preview widget with zooming capabilities, eg. `Filters > Light and Shadow > Lens Flare` ([Lens Flare Dialog](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/plug-in-flarefx.html)). Perhaps some developer in the future upgrades the dialog and replaces the basic preview with a zoomable one.